# How can I make my Windows API GUI code more object-oriented?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

For a class project I am creating a tic tac toe game with a GUI. The assignment requires the use of classes.

The assignment didn't originally require a GUI, so I created a working tic tac toe game with a command line interface. However, to earn some extra points I'd now like to implement a GUI. The problem is we haven't covered GUI design.

So far, I am able to display a window with 9 buttons on it. As you can see from the code below this is all done without classes. How could I separate my code into a single class or classes? Then, how would I display the GUI after creating an object in main?

I'm not trying to bring on any framework dependencies beyond the already-included windows.h system header.

In the end I'd like to have a class to handle the interface and a class to handle the logic.

Thanks for any suggestions

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
  MSG  msg ;    
  WNDCLASS wc = {0};
  wc.lpszClassName = TEXT( "Buttons" );
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);


  RegisterClass(&wc);
  CreateWindow( wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("Buttons"),
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                150, 150, 340, 360, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  

  while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{


  switch(msg)  
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     20, 20, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     120, 20, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL); 

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     220, 20, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL); 

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     20, 120, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 4, NULL, NULL);

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     120, 120, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 5, NULL, NULL);    

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     220, 120, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 5, NULL, NULL); 

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     20, 220, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL); 

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     120, 220, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL); 

        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(""),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                     220, 220, 80, 80,        
                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);                                                       
        break;
    }
        // incomplete
      case WM_COMMAND:
      {
       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
           Beep(40, 50);
       }

       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
              PostQuitMessage(0);
       }

       break;
       }

      case WM_DESTROY:
      {
         PostQuitMessage(0);
         break;
      }
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: take a look at MFC or Qt. optionally also read about mvc pattern

Comment: I'd rather not look at anything else. I want to do this with only windows.h.

Comment: @Hayri Uğur Koltuk I'll start reading about mvc pattern. Thanks

Comment: The mvc pattern will be a lot of work implementing with just the WinAPI especially if the goal is just to add a GUI to text based tic tac toe game.

Comment: @drescherjm Well that's not the way I want to go then. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. Right now all I'm trying to do is create a class that displays nine buttons.

Comment: @drescherjm oh the irony, http://pastebin.com/N9U2vGGG didn't go well. Sorry for the late reply I must have forgot to press enter in a different tab or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Raymond Chen's C++ version of his scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx)

It shows you how to use C++ classes (and member functions) together with the C-style callback approach used by the Windows API.  Pretty much all his blog posts are worth reading, if you're interested in how to do things well in Windows, and why the APIs work the way they do.

But, there's still a lot that can be improved in Raymond's program, especially with the new `std::unique_ptr` (it didn't exist in 2005 when his post appeared, and he has a reputation for actually writing those over two years before they become public, so he may have not even had C++03 to work with).

Nonetheless, it shows you how to store a `this` pointer in a Win32 GUI object and how to dispatch messages to member functions for handling.

Comment: And I would upvote for WTL as well (as you mentioned in the comment in the previous answer)  Its relatively lightweight (vs Qt) and easy to get started with.

Comment: @CoreyStup: In a related question he mentioned that it has to compile on his professor's test machine, which rules out downloads of third-party libraries.  Otherwise WTL would be an excellent addition.